# Как исказить картинку?

Tags: python

Есть вариант, чтобы сделать из картинки негатив.

```
    with open('bmp_file.bmp', mode='rb') as inputfile:
    header = inputfile.read(54)
    res = [255 - val for val in inputfile.read()]
    with  open("bmp_file_negative.bmp", mode="wb") as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(header)
        outputfile.write(bytes(res))
```

Он рабочий.

Теперь вопрос: как сделать, чтобы вылетали пиксели с картинки(случайным образом!) (то есть она искажалась так)?
Вот пример. Картинка каждый раз должна "ехать" случайным образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там где с поездом - чтобы так исказить цвет, можно менять местами каналы RGB

Comment: Цвет менять не надо( надо сделать, чтобы вылетали байты. Допустим, я изменил какой-то случайный байт и картинка полетела случайным образом

Comment: @otowanmr Это испортит всю картинку, только если данные упакованы каким-то образом. Я просто уже не помню формат `bmp`. Если там хотя бы `RLE` используется, то картинка должна "поехать", а если там "сырые данные" байт в байт, то от искажения одного байта исказится ровно один байт, и не более того.

Comment: otowanmr зачем вы удалили вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270843 ? Если восстановите, я попробую на него глянуть.

Comment: @S. Nick Спасибо большое, с тем уже вроде как разобрался, но вылезла другая ошибка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271067/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b9-txt-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/1271068#1271068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покопался я в Google Colab, получилось примерно так:

```
import PIL
import random

filename = '/usr/local/cuda-10.1/samples/3_Imaging/bilateralFilter/data/nature_monte.bmp'
testname = 'test.bmp'
im=PIL.Image.open(filename)

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data = bytearray(f.read())

header = 53
for i in range(5):
    x = random.randint(0, im.width - 1)
    y = random.randint(0, im.height - 1)
    c = random.randint(0, 2)
    shift = random.randint(1, 100)
    pos = header + (im.width * y + x) * 3 + c
    data[header:pos-shift] = data[header+shift:pos]

with open(testname, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)

im=PIL.Image.open(testname)
im
```

Исходная картинка:

[image: исходная картинка]

Искаженная картинка:

[image: искаженная картинка]

Как я и думал, исказить один байт (или даже 3 байта) оказалось недостаточно для несжатого формата картинки. Данные нужно именно сдвигать на сколько-то байт. Чтобы при этом "поехало" не только изображение, но и цвет, сдвиг должен производиться на число байт, не кратное 3-м. Ещё нужно отметить, что картинка в байтах идёт от нижнего левого угла, а не от верхнего, поэтому сдвигать данные приходится не в конец, а наоборот в начало.